# How to solve combined differential equations in python?

Tags: python, equation, solver, odeint

I have a system of equations as following. I want to plot u1, u2, u3, u4, ud, p1, p2, p3, p4, deltapL, deltapR against time.

My code doesn't seem to work, and do not know why since I have more equations than unknowns.[Set of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iTod.png)

The code i am using is:

```
def myFunction(r,t):
g = 9.81
L_L = 11
L_r = 11
L_d = 30
u_s = 0.08
w_d = 3
w_r = 10
w_L = 10

u_1 = r[0]
u_2 = r[1]
u_3 = r[2]
u_4 = r[3]
u_d = r[4]
p_1 = r[5]
p_4 = r[6]
deltap_L = r[7]
deltap_R = r[8]

u_1 = (L_L*u_s + w_L*u_2)/w_L
u_2 = (w_d*u_d)/w_L
u_3 = (w_L*u_2)/w_r
u_4 = (L_r*u_s + w_r*u_3)/w_r
u_d = (w_r*u_3)/w_d
dp1dt = - u_1
dp4dt = u_4 
du1dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L - deltap_L/L_L) - u_1
du2dt =  - g*((p_2-p_1)/L_L - deltap_L/L_L) - u_2
du3dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r + deltap_R/L_r) - u_3
du4dt =  - g*((p_4-p_3)/L_r + deltap_R/L_r) - u_4
duddt =  - g*((p_3-p_2)/L_d) - u_d
return (du1dt, du2dt, du3dt, du4dt, duddt, dp1dt, dp4dt, deltap_L, deltap_R)


r0 = ([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
t = np.linspace(0,10)
r = odeint(myFunction, r0, t)




u1 = r[:,0]
u2 = r[:,1]
u3 = r[:,2]
u4 = r[:,3]
ud = r[:,4]
p1 = r[:,5]
#p2 = r[:,6]
#p3 = r[:,7]
p4 = r[:,6]
deltap_L = r[:,7]
deltap_R = r[:,8]

plt.figure(figsize = (15,6))
plt.suptitle('Symmetric situation')
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(t, u1)
plt.plot(t, u2)
plt.plot(t, u3)
plt.plot(t, u4)
plt.plot(t, ud)
plt.legend(('$u_1$', '$u_2$', '$u_3$', '$u_4$', '$u_d$'))
plt.xlabel('Time ($s$)')
plt.ylabel('fluid velocity ($m/s$)')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(t, p1)
plt.plot(t, p4)
plt.plot(t, deltap_L)
plt.plot(t, deltap_R)
plt.legend(('$\u03B4 p_L$', '$\u03B4 p_R$'))
plt.xlabel('Time ($s$)')
plt.ylabel('Pressure ($m$)')
```

I've been stuck on this for a while so yes I tried adding p2 and p3 as well. I am just wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: What and how exactly doesn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It keeps telling me that I need to define p_2, however p_2 is also dependent on time.

Comment: Could you provide concrete error message?

Comment: And what do you mean "dependent on time"? By the way, `p_2` is used in your code but never assigned with a value.